# Error message when importing QuPATH Image Alignment extension

Tags: image, alignment, qupath

I am a new QuPATH user, using version 0.4.3.  I am looking to align serial sections for multiplex immunofluorescence stains. To do this, I followed the instructions on the following webpage:

https://qupath.readthedocs.io/en/0.4/docs/intro/extensions.html

I downloaded the .jar file from here: https://github.com/qupath/qupath-extension-align (file name: qupath-extension-align-0.4.0.jar).  I then dragged it into the main QuPATH window and selected a user directory to store the extension in.  However, it did not properly import into QuPATH.  I am very new to both QuPATH and coding in general, so am not sure where to start with troubleshooting.

Upon loading in the .jar file, I closed QuPATH and reopened as recommended.  The following error message came up (see attached photo).  It seems that maybe it is incompatible with my QuPATH version?  I know the .jar file says 0.4.0 and my version is 0.4.3. Maybe this is the issue?

Thanks!

(https://i.stack.imgur.com/bZziS.png)